# aws adding the load balancer with same SSL certs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have two components of the service (frontend and backend). The service has some SSL certs and I am trying to use the same SSL certificates and uploading them to the aws using `aws acm`. When I am doing `aws acm list-certificates --region us-west-2`, I am getting the list of two `CertificateArn` with the same Domain name.

Expected: I want two load balancer, one for backend and one for frontend. How can I achieve this?

Service 1:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "haproxy-ingress"
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: subnet-0b52a56cbb1dd0673, subnet-0f610a337c06e665d
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn-value-1
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: 200-399
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-interval-seconds: '300'
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
         - path: /*
           backend:
             serviceName: ssl-redirect
             servicePort: use-annotation
         - path: /*
           backend:
             serviceName: service-1
             servicePort: 80

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-1
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn-value-1
spec:
  ports:
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: service-1
```

Service 2:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: "haproxy-ingress"
      namespace: kube-system
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: subnet-0b52a56cbb1dd0673, subnet-0f610a337c06e665d
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn-value-1
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS":443}]'
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: 200-399
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-interval-seconds: '300'
    spec:
      rules:
        - http:
            paths:
             - path: /*
               backend:
                 serviceName: ssl-redirect
                 servicePort: use-annotation
             - path: /*
               backend:
                 serviceName: service-2
                 servicePort: 80
    
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: service-2
      namespace: kube-system
      annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn-value-1
    spec:
      ports:
        - name: https
          protocol: TCP
          port: 443
          targetPort: 8080
        - name: http
          protocol: TCP
          port: 80
          targetPort: 8080
      type: ClusterIP
      selector:
        app: service-2
```

Comment: It sounds like you have uploaded the SSL certificate to ACM twice. You should probably delete one of them? Or just pick one and use it with both load balancers.

Comment: @MarkB I thought that we need to have the `certificatearn` value in ingress controller which needs to be deployed to setup the k8s resources. Hence, I uploaded the cert twice. If I use the same `certificatearn` and deploy the k8s yaml files, how is the service going to use a different load balancer?

Comment: "If I use the same certificatearn and deploy the k8s yaml files, how is the service going to use a different load balancer?" Is this an actual issue you are encountering, or something you are predicting will be an issue? You can create as many load balancers as you need, and assign a single ACM to as many load balancers as you want.

Comment: @MarkB I changed the service and ingress.yaml files and used `kubectl` to apply these files.. Still only one load balancer

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use the same SSL certificate you will only need to upload the certificate to ACM once. Both certificates will have the same domain name as this is the primary domain name included in the certificate, if you're looking to validate any secondary names these can be found by running the [describe-certificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/acm/describe-certificate.html) function and accessing the contents of the `SubjectAlternativeNames` attribute.

When you create the load balancers you would simply specify the same ACM Arn for the listeners in both load balancers.

Comment: I thought that we need to have the `certificatearn` value in ingress controller which needs to be deployed to setup the k8s resources. Hence, I uploaded the cert twice. If I use the same `certificatearn` and deploy the k8s yaml files, how is the service going to use a different load balancer? I just want two load balancer with same SSL.

Comment: The certificate arn is different from the load balancer, if you specify the same Arn it should still create another load balancer assuming your configuration files not represent the same resource.

Comment: I changed the service and ingress.yaml files still only one load balancer.

Comment: Are these referencing 2 completely different services? Otherwise they will just be overwriting the previous one :(

Comment: the service name is different and I am getting `ingress.extensions/haproxy-ingress unchanged` when I applied the ingress file if that helps. sorry for the annoying issue

Comment: Can you paste copies of the configurations (for both proposed load balancers) as it will make it easier to see if there is a similarity between both :)

Comment: the ingress and service.yaml are pasted.